# python pandas : compare two columns for equality and result in third dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, concatenation

how to print the result in the separate dataframe after comparing it with two columns in different dataframes.

consider two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['audi','cars']})  
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2':['audi','bike']})

print (df1)

    col1
0  audi
1  cars 

print (df2)

     col2
0   audi
1   bike
```

now the result should be in a different dataframe.

```
      col1  col2  result
0     audi  audi   no change
1     cars  bike   changed
```

Answer (score 17):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df['result'] = np.where(df['col1'] == df['col2'], 'no change', 'changed')
print (df)
   col1  col2     result
0  audi  audi  no change
1  cars  bike    changed
```

Comment: when I used this I am getting the following warning `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` is there an another way

Comment: @Jeril - Obviously problem is in another code, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas/53954986#53954986)